# MySQL query in two tables output not generated correctly

Tags: mysql, join

My first table 'table1'  :

```
------|----------|----------|
| Id  |   Name   | Location |
------|----------|----------|
| 1   | Ashish   |   1,2    |
------|----------|----------|
| 2   |  Jay     |    3     |
------|----------|----------|
| 3   | Sabir    |   4,1    |
------|----------|----------|
```

My second table 'table2' :

```
 |------|----------|----------|
 | Id   |   Location_name     | 
 |------|----------|----------|
 |  1   |     Ahmedabad       |             
 |------|----------|----------|
 |  2   |       Keshod        |
 |------|----------|----------|
 |  3   |       Junagadh      |
 |----- |----------|----------|
 |  4   |       Rajkot        |
 |----- |----------|----------|
```

I try this query but output not generated correctly :

```
Select t1.Name,t2.Location_name from table1 as t1 Left Join table2 as t2 ON t1.Location = t2.Id WHERE t1.Location IN (t1.Location)
```

Output will be generated is :

```
 |-----------|---------------------------|
 | Name      |   Location_name           | 
 |-----------|---------------------------|
 |  Ashish   |    Ahmedabad              |             
 |-----------|---------------------------|
 |  Jay      |    Junagadh               |             
 |-----------|---------------------------|
 |  Sabir    |    Rajkot                 |             
 |-----------|---------------------------|
```

But i want to this output:

```
 |-----------|---------------------------|
 | Name      |   Location_name           | 
 |-----------|---------------------------|
 |  Ashish   |    Ahmedabad,Keshod       |             
 |-----------|---------------------------|
 |  Jay      |    Junagadh               |             
 |-----------|---------------------------|
 |  Sabir    |    Rajkot,Ahmedabad       |             
 |-----------|---------------------------|
```

Comment: MySQL cannot understand that your `Location` column is a comma separated list. You need to add multiple rows for multiple locations.

Comment: @PrerakSola ok, any other solution for this output in one query ?

Comment: Another solution? Yes. See normalisation.

Comment: Check this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/54b16/1 I have changed your table structure. Have a look at it. The query is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT t1.name, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.location_name) FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(t2.id, t1.location)
GROUP BY t1.id
```

OR Using LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT t1.name,GROUP_CONCAT(t2.location_name) FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON FIND_IN_SET(t2.id, t1.location)
GROUP BY t1.id
```

Comment: Thanks PravinS this one is exactly for me.again thanks.